# Pulling specific MAC/IP-addresses from Wi-fi router and directed them to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, ip-address, mac-address, network-analysis

The purpose of our project is to “sniff” for specific MAC/IP-addresses so we can use the MAC/IP-addresses to turn off or on the alarm system. 
The idea is to automate the alarm system in “our house”.  We have one raspberry Pi with installed Linux Mate that we are going to use to monitor the network with, one Raspberry Pi to turn on and off the alarm and a router for WLAN for the devices to connect.

We would have rather used MAC addresses over IP addresses as it probably is more secure, but MAC addresses are probably harder to manage.

We are using a TP-Link tl-wr841nd.

Does anyone have tips on how we can progress in this matter?

Comment: Neither an IP not a MAC address on its own give any secure identification. "…to turn on and off the alarm and a router for WLAN…" How are planing to get the address if the WLAN is switched off?

Comment: Use wireshark or it's console variant tshark.You can write a bash script that uses tshark with the filters you want.

Comment: @KlausD. This is a school project as of right now the security asspect of it is not that important. This is more like a proof of consept than a fullt fledged home security system. There will be a physical display and notepad is the WLAN is down.

Comment: @brunorey We have already installed wireshark on our raspberry and are currently observind and experimenting with sniffing and analysing the network. Do you have any suggestions on good forums or guides about bash scripting with tshark?